# Prevent default username & password from being used by php to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, linux, apache

I tried searching but the answers to similar questions didn't solve my problem.

I am trying to connect to MySQL database from a PHP code like this:

```
$con = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
```

where

```
$hostname = "localhost" , $username = "xxx" , $password = "yyy"
```

When I try to access this php page from browser, I get this error message:

> Could not connect: Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I understand that www-data is the default username used by the apache webserver and it does not have a password. Since this user hasn't been configured in MySQL, connection is refused.

My question is how I could prevent the default username from getting used. I would want the php code to try connecting to MySQL using the username "xxx" and password "yyy"

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Try to comment out your code and see what will happen - I think this error comes from another place in your script.

Answer (score 1):

Writing mysqli_connect() should solve your problem and use mysqli instead of mysql as suggested by teresko.